# How do you populate a @html.dropdownlist with content from a database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am currently face with a problem and hope that you can help. I am struggling with gathering information from a database to allow population of the drop downlist. Below is the code in my controller,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  tblProductColour db = new tblProductColour();
  this.ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(db.tblproducts.ToList(), "Id", "ProductColour");
  return View();
}
```

Here is the code used within the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id")
```

Thanks in advance,

Callum

Comment: The error that i am receiving is that there is no information being passed through from the model itself.

Comment: Whats with the "blockquote" at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you could stuff the contents of the database into a `ViewBag` like this:

`ViewBag.identifier = new SelectList(db.databaseName, "Id", "ProductColour");`

Then in your view you show the `ViewBag` like this:

`@Html.DropDownList("identifier", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Assuming you are using `bootstrap`.. hence the `class` name of `form-control`

Make sure if the dropdownlist is going to be used in a `POST` Action to put the `ViewBag` in both Actions of the Controller..

For example..

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.identifier = new SelectList(db.databaseName, "Id", "ProductColour");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id, ProductColour")] #modelName identify)
{
    ViewBag.identifier = new SelectList(db.databaseName, "Id", "ProductColour", identify.Id);
}
```

Assuming you have a connection string assigned to a variable called `db`

Comment: Thanks for your help. That has made a huge difference and allowed me to complete the task.